# how to send bold or italic messege for api bot telegram?

Tags: sendmessage, telegram, telegram-bot

how to send bold or italic messege for api bot telegram?

```
https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage?parse_mod=Markdown&chat_id=@testadminch&text=*bold*
```

output is: `*bold*`
but should is: **bold**

sorry for my bad english

Comment: try `parse_mode=markdown`

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `parse_mode` to `markdown`

```
$post = array("chat_id" => $id, "text"=> $text, "parse_mode" => "markdown");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $GLOBALS["token"] . "/sendMessage");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec ($ch);    
curl_close ($ch);
```